# Send changed price to cart page in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm new to shopify and meet this issue.

Let's assume that you owned a printing company and build the website.

Every printing has its own size.

So there is just only standard price for square cm, not for every variant.

So in product detail page if you input width and height then the price is automatically calculated using jquery now.

Then when I click add to cart button I want to send my price to cart page, but it shows default price on cart page for that product.

How can I do this?

I tried to using Shopify Ajax but it's not working.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculate how many units your customer wants multiplying length times width. That is a number. Say 12 x 12 for something. It costs $1.62 per square unit. You add variant ID 123456789xyz to the cart with a POST using either typical form submit OR equally valid, an ajax POST, with the quantity set to 144 and the variant ID. It works perfect. I have done that pattern for millions of dollars in sales with Shopify.

So the lesson for you is not to send the price to the cart, but instead, the variant ID and the quantity. Price is taken care of internal to Shopify and you cannot monkey with that.

Comment: you mean create a variant on cart page? How can I do it?

Comment: No... create nothing... every product has one or more variants. When you deal with Shopify, any cart operation (add/remove/update) involves only two things for the most part: a variant ID and a quantity. You don't create them, you use them. Inspect your theme code to see how you do it.

Comment: not static. Any customer can customize size. So there is no static variant id

Comment: You do not understand. Variant ID is static. Quantity is not. Customer changes sizes YES, and you place that size in Quantity field. POST the variant ID and quantity to the cart.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense now.  Create variant with 1cm * 1cm and then when you custom size change the quantity. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes. Create a variant with a single unit. Give it a price. You are smarter than the average bear as they say.

Comment: Hi @DavidLazar regarding your suggestion, I have implemented what you said above, but when i redirect my customers to checkout it shows that they have purchased that quantity of the product (ie quantity would be 144 going along with your example above). Is there a way to override the way the quantity is shown in the checkout url?

Comment: Nope. You are stuck with units sold. I believe Euro people are given access to units separate from quantity. You might want to look into that. My recipe pre-dates Shopify providing units.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @DavidLazar. How do you handle adding measurements to products now? I can't seem to find a way to do it (I'm using the storefront api to integrate with shopify btw)